# Jquery 1 + 1 = 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a some problem on my jquery code.

I want counting 1 + 1 in jquery but the result is "11" not "2" ... so where the problem ??

Here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var hasil = $(".hitdethasil>.hasildet");
    var bhit = $(".hitung");

    $(bhit).click(function(){
        var ske = $(".iUn").val(); //assume is 1
        var ska = $(".ia").val(); //assume is 1
        var beda = $(".ib").val(); //assume is 1
        var hasilarit = ska + (ske - 1) * beda; //but in this result is 10 should the result is 1.
        $(hasil).text(hasilarit);
        console.log(hasilarit);
    });

    $(".iUn").keyup(function () {
        var thisis = $(this).val();
        $(".skun").text(thisis);
    });
});
```

Where does the fault ????

Thanks B4 and i'm sorry for my bad english ... :)

Here is JsFiddle to see the problem ... http://jsfiddle.net/bagusa4/mqLqoL7o/

Comment: Values of inputs are strings.

Comment: `+` acts as string concat operator. Use `parseInt()` or `Number()`

Comment: `$.fn.val` returns a string. So prepend `$` with `+` , and it will become a number.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/mqLqoL7o/1/  - I use parseInt() to turn them into numbers. It should work. I was in the middle of posting an answer when this was closed, but you should be able to find any other information you need in the previous post.

Comment: @zfrisch thanks! has been edit my jsfiddle to show the example you mean :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `var ske = $(".iUn").val();` is "1" not 1. The same holds for the other textbox. So "1"+"1"="11", which is the expected.

Otherwise, you should use the `parseInt` -assuming that the input will be an integer. Otherwise you should use the `parseFloat` function-.

```
var ske = parseInt($(".iUn").val());
```